# Indent part of JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

Is there a way to indent text in a jtextpane using insertString? My question is similar to [JTextPane indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052061/jtextpane-indentation) except that I would very much prefer to use insertString